# How can I turn off the radio devices in my laptop to ensure the plane I'm flying on doesn't crash and kill us all?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have an EEE 1000H netbook. It's running Arch Linux. I need to know how to turn off the Bluetooth and WiFi cards to ensure they don't crash my plane...

There's two ways I'm thinking of to do this. Either boot up into Arch and turn them off from there or, to be paranoid, I'll boot up into BIOS and turn the hardware off.

Am I missing anything? How have you EEE owners handled this?

I'd like to not have the news headlines report of a plane crash because some idiot didn't turn off their netbook.

Comment: ... A lot of planes now allow Wifi and infact sell wireless internet, the reason for them not allowing was more better safe than sorry than anything else.

Comment: Oh? There's nothing I should be worried about with having it running during flight?

Comment: The chances of at least 1 passenger not turning off their phone or wifi on a plane (whether intentionally or not) are pretty much 100%, and I've never heard of planes crashing that way, so yeah.

Comment: Alright. Cheers for the help ;)

Comment: If small electronics could crash a plane just like that, do you think that they would let you take them aboard? Still, it may be smart to wait until the plane actually lifts off because some RADAR devices use same frequency range (S band) as WiFi and could make problems with connection.

Comment: I have fun on planes, trying to connect to other people's laptops through Bluetooth. Once I could see the Macbook Pro owner a few seats across from me start panicing.

Comment: Every flight I have been on, you are asked to turn off all electronics during take-off and landing.

Comment: The problem was that when mobile phones go not find a signal, they increase the power they output until they either get a signal or reach their maximum power output. Several phones at maximum power is thought to have the possibility of interfering with the plane's communication systems, although I've never heard this actually happen. On a side note, planes are moving from _fly-by-wire_ to _wireless_ solutions to decrease weight (8km of copper cable = heavy), where interference could actually cause major problems.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is old but this works on all laptops I've tried it on. First install rfkill (question was for Arch so this is what the example reflect)

```
pacman -S rfkill
```

... then use rfkill to turn off bluetooth, wifi, everything or get a list by using rfkill help.

```
# rfkill block bluetooth
# rfkill block wifi
# rfkill block all
```

use to reactivate the module again:

```
# rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$ exec sudo shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 3):

I've no experience with bluetooth, but I believe that `sudo ifdown wlan0` does the trick to turn the wifi off, assuming you're NOT using NetworkManager (if you are, the interface will shut off, but things go screwy once NetworkManager realizes it's off).

`sudo service NetworkManager stop` or `sudo /etc/init.d/NetworkManager stop` stops the NetworkManager service, which sometimes turns off the wireless card, as well.  If it doesn't, proceed with `ifdown wlan0`.

Finally, this answer is for completeness's sake; I hold with the opinions of the commenters, that being that wifi and bluetooth are unlikely to send your airplane into a nosedive.  Unless you're the [PHB](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1997-09-10/), that is.

Comment: "things go screwy once NetworkManager realizes it's off" - Very true. Network Manager is highly illogical.